# How to use a each loop variable in a condition in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

My pipeline task needs to iterate using an each and then process a condition. How can I use the each variable in a condition.

```
- ${{ each myitem in parameters.itemList }}:
- script: echo "Matched for ${{ myitem }}"
  displayName: "Display item only on condition"
  condition: eq(variables['myPipelinevariable'], ${{ myitem }})
```

In the above condition clause{{ myitem }} does not evaluate to its value and I get the error message Unrecognized value: '$'

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error on the value of the **`condition`** key.

```yaml
# Incorrect syntax.
condition: eq(variables['myPipelinevariable'], ${{ myitem }})
```

The correct syntax should be the following.

```yaml
# Correct syntax.
condition: ${{ eq(variables['myPipelinevariable'], myitem) }}
```

So, the configuration on your script task should look like below.

```yaml
- ${{ each myitem in parameters.itemList }}:
  - script: echo "Matched for ${{ myitem }}"
    displayName: "Display item only on condition"
    condition: ${{ eq(variables['myPipelinevariable'], myitem) }}
```